# Edit scope rule after migration from SP2010 to 2013

Tags: search, search-scope

We're running SP2010 under `http://sp2010` (example), I did a test migration to 2013 and call it `http://2013`

We're not doing the visual upgrade yet so stuck with SP2010 search web parts (using scopes that is).

Scopes have been replaced by Result Sources but I can't use them until we do the visual upgrade?

The issue I have is that I have scope rules with include/exclude addresses like

include `http://sp2010/sites/somesite` I crawl the content on the new server but search doesn't return anything because the scope is restricted to the old URLs. In search admin the option to change the URL is greyed out, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Should have waited 10 min with that post..

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "Search Service Application"
$scope = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScope -Identity SomeScope -SearchApplication $ssa

$scope.Rules

$rule = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule -Scope $scope -Url http://sp2013 -Identity 3
$rule.MatchingString =  "http://sp2013/sites/somesite"
$rule.Update()
```